# Careers job application feedback

Tags: support, jobs, email

After applying for a job on careers.stackoverflow, I got an automatic email and that's it. Is there a transparent known process that follows this action or is it just an ad-hoc one that depends on the employer that posted the jobs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The email we send you after you've completed your application is to let you know we've received it and have passed it on to the employer who posted the job. Once we've done this your application is out of our hands, and then enters whatever process the employer has in place to deal with received applications.

Comment: What if the employer is stackexchange? :)