# Make it clear what exactly we flagged

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags, flag-history

In the flag summary page, we see now all kinds of flags we submitted including comment flags that until recently were not visible in the summary except for raw number on the side. That's all good.

However, each item still show only either "asked" or "answered" with the question/answer author. For comment flag it can be rather confusing as it appears we flagged the post which is not  true. Example:

> [image]

I flagged a comment posted [on this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187857/152859), not the question itself.

I suggest something like this instead:

> [image]

Where "foo" is the comment author.

Comment: The first time I saw this I thought I'd misflagged

Comment: This can be even more confusing if you have flagged both a post and a comment on it: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dJVUu.jpg