# Confused about my comment flag(s). Helpful? Or rude or offensive?

Tags: support, comment-flags, flag-history

Does this mean I've got both flags on one comment? it's not clear what the "rude or offensive" and "helpful" text is referring to here. And which comment is actually flagged?  It almost looks like I flagged my own comment.

[image]

Comment: [This feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188948/make-it-clear-what-exactly-we-flagged) will probably prevent such confusion.

Comment: Close Voters - this question here appears to be more about the name added after the flag reason, which I don't think existed before, and makes it look like a comment, i.e. it appears indeed that the user himself has been flagged, and not the one flagging.

Answer (score 3):

*You* flagged this as "rude or offensive". A moderator found it helpful that you did so.

(Otherwise, it would say "declined" in dark red, instead of "helpful".)