# Make it more obvious that I'm banned only from flagging posts, not comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, wording, flag-ban

Currently, the flag ban notice in the flag summary page looks like that:

[image]

> You are currently banned from flagging - view flags declined in the last 7 days

It looks as if I was banned from flagging anything, but in fact I'm only banned from flagging posts; I can still flag comments (I assume this isn't a bug). Could the notice be changed to make it more obvious? Just changing "flagging" to "flagging posts" should be sufficient.

Comment: Well, the flag history page is very lacking when it concerns comment flags, e.g. it even [doesn't show we flagged a comment in the first place](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188948/make-it-clear-what-exactly-we-flagged). But yeah, totally agree the current message is confusing.

Comment: Wait, so declining comments flags doesn't actually stop them from generating more crappy comment flags? Well crap.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh, I didn't even know we can't tell. But there are under different categories, for example, you can't flag posts for "obsolete", "not constructive", "too chatty", "Rude or offensive" for comment is different from "Rude or abusive". Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: @ShadowtheWelcomingWizard How long does this flag ban last? 24 hours or 1 week? Why doesn't it tell the period of ban?

Comment: @sv. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/310998

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski Yes, read that one before but the answer is vague especially, "Depending on when and how those declined flags were cast, this block could last for as little as a day, and won't ever be longer than a week"...how to figure out if it's a day or a week?

Comment: @sv. the key is "past 7 days", meaning the check if you're flag banned is done on the fly, checking the flags you submitted in the last 7 days. If you submitted at least 10, and 25% of those or more were declined (e.g. 10 flags, 3 declined) then you're banned. Since it's dynamic and can change any moment (e.g. another flag you submitted yesterday is declined), the amount of time left for the ban is unknown.

Comment: @ShadowtheWelcomingWizard Ok. Thanks. So, how to get out of this ban if the system won't let me flag new posts to improve my flag weight? Just check every day so the declined flags get older? What if a mod made an error in declining a flag? Can they reverse it so the ban is also automatically removed?

Comment: @sv. Yes just wait... And yes as far as I know, moderator should be able to dispute or approve a declined flag and thus lift a flag ban.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the next build, the ban message on your flag summary page will contain the word "posts":

> [image: You may raise flags again in 7 days]