# Show which comment was flagged when reviewing flag summary

Tags: feature-request, flags, comment-flags, flag-history

I've noticed that if you click a declined comment flag in your flag summary, it takes you to the question the comment was posted on - not the comment on the question.

Would it make better sense to take you to the specific comment you flagged on the question? This could help when reviewing your flags to know for the future which comments should be flagged and which shouldn't.

For example, clicking 'search text highlighting is borked' in my flag summary takes me to the actual question:

[image]

My suggestion is that it should automatically scroll down to the comment you flagged and highlight it i.e with a border. For example - and this is a random comment on the question as I don't know which comment I originally flagged:

[image]

Comment: Very related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188948/make-it-clear-what-exactly-we-flagged.

Answer (score 4):

> This could help when reviewing your flags to know for the future which comments should be flagged and which shouldn't.

Yes, this is a good reason to implement this feature request, so +1 from me. However, you can already see which comment it is (unless it was deleted for another reason than your flag): try to flag it and you'll see whether you've cast a flag on it:

[image]

(Of course, this gets tedious in long comment threads, but at least you have a workaround now.)